# Is it possible to access a different node from another different node in drupal

Tags: drupal

I have this node named Movies, and i have another node named casts. So when i delete a cast i want it to reflect to the movies node. Is it possible to access a field in movies node when im in casts node? how do i do that in drupal? im using drupal 6 by the way

Comment: use node reference module then in movies content type use casts as node reference then it show reflect

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do that from a module or some PHP code? You can use [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7).

If want you really want is to delete a node and have the references to it cleared automatically, you can use [node_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete/7)

Just be careful that you are using Drupal in the appropiate way. Maybe you would prefer to have a entity reference field in your Movies node to each one of your 'Actors' (or Cast, if you prefer to keep them grouped, although i wouldn't see why) nodes.

Comment: i cant see how node_load can load a different node. can you explain further how to use that node_load? And yes, my casts are referenced to certain movies. im using drupal 6 by the way

Comment: i understand now how to do it. but im confused on how to traverse to the right nid. i have this code so far $node->field_movie_cast[0]['nid']. how do i point to the specific nid?

Comment: I could explain more, but the whole idea about using drupal is that you don't have to do such things in 99.99% of the cases. What are you trying to accomplish? I am sure there is an easier, more robust and alternative way than transversing the array hierarchy.

Comment: this is the scenario. When i delete a certain person type. Its nid remains in the person type reference field in a movie type, although it is already deleted in the database and i dont know why. so what im trying to do is that whenever i delete a person, all movies that has a reference to that person would be cleared of its nid.

Comment: as silentob said in his response, CCK removes automatically the references, you just need to use [node_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete/7) to delete your person node and the reference should be removed too. I have modified the answer to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with SQL it is shorter and more efficient than node_load/node_save:

```
db_query("DELETE FROM content_field_movie_cast WHERE field_movie_cast_nid = %d", $person->nid);
```

(I'm guessing at your content naming there so it would probably need some tweaking.)

With that said, by default CCK will remove any node references when the node is deleted, so you shouldn't have to manually do any cleanup.  Are you directly deleting the person with SQL?